# Default Activity not found

Tags: android

Después de haber eliminado y volver a crear una actividad tengo el siguiente  problema a la hora de iniciar mi aplicación, me sale "Default Activity not found" , este es el fichero AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SegActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".TerceraActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".QuartActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".FinalActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

y el MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Comprueba tus nombres de tus actividades, ya que se llama MainActivity y la que esta buscando se llama DefaultActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que tener en tu aplicación una `Activity` "default" que inicie la aplicación, para este caso debe tener definido el suguiente `intent-filter`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Agregala a tu Activity Principal, por ejemplo:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasó que quise cambiar cuál era la Activity que inicializaba y solo cambié la categoría de DEFAULT a LAUNCHER pero le dejé el nombre que tenía, "OPCIONES"

```
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPCIONES" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Es importante cambiarle el nombre a MAIN para que funcione. O sea, tu activity debe tener esto sí o sí para que sea la que arranque:

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Al cambiarle el nombre de "OPCIONES" a "MAIN"  y cambiar la que había quedado con MAIN a otro nombre  funcionó correctamente.